# This regex in JS rerturns an unexpected value

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't find the problem here and doesn't matter what I try, I don't understand the results

I have this in a script:

```
var pattern = "(\d*(?=,))";
var regex = new RegExp( pattern, "i" );
var string_to_match = "[\w\s-]{3,}";
var match = regex.exec( string_to_match );
alert( match.length ); --> prints 2
alert( typeof( match )); --> prints object

alert( match[0] ); --> prints nothing, or empty space
alert( match[0].length ); --> prints 0
alert( typeof( match[0] )); --> prints string

alert( match[1] ); --> prints nothing, or empty space
alert( match[1].length ); --> prints 0
alert( typeof( match[1] )); --> prints string
```

This is just the last version of the test I'm doing. In the real/final script, the string to match comes from HTML code. Always in the same format, just changing the numbers.

On every regex tester that I have tried, the result is as expected, it comes up with the number in match[0]

So, what am I doing wrong? What am I missing here?

**Update after the answer:**

with the combination below, works as expected

```
var regex = /(\d*(?=,))/i;
```

with the combination below, works as expected

```
var pattern = "(\\d*(?=,))";
var regex = new RegExp( pattern, "i" );
```

with the combination below, it doesn't work

```
var pattern = "/(\d*(?=,))/";
var regex = new RegExp( pattern, "i" );
```

So, just adding the slashes as delimiters, doesn't work. I tried that in my original attempt since I'm used to regexes in PHP. Escaping the slash in \d did the trick. I though that pattern was being passed literally to the regexp object not interpreted, but that was my problem.

Comment: What's `string_to_match` ?

Comment: Use `console.log` to debug instead of alert

Comment: The resulting regular expression is just `/(d*(?=,))/i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the `\d`. Either change it to `\\d`, or use slashes to delimit the regex:

```
var regex = /(\d*(?=,))/i;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added and update with tests regarding the options you mentioned.